# (Python)Facing an error while building a bot

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

This is the code I wrote to run my Discord Bot. It tells current status of Minecraft servers in an embed.

```py
import discord
import os
import requests
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "//")

@client.command()
async def mc(ctx, arg):    
   url = "https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/"
   data = requests.get(url + arg ).json()
   print(data)
   ip = data["ip"]
   port = data["port"]
   ping = str(data["debug"]["ping"])
   motd = data["motd"]["clean"]
   onlineplayers = str(data["players"]["online"])
   onlineplayersname = data["players"]["list"]
   version = str(data["version"])
   online = str(data["online"])
   protocol = str(data["protocol"])
   hostname = data["hostname"]

   embed = discord.Embed(
     title = arg + " Server Info",
     description = motd,
     color = 0xff00,
   )

   embed.add_field(
     name = "I.P. Address",
     value = ip
   )
   embed.add_field(
     name = "Port",
     value = port
   )

   embed.add_field(
     name = "Can server be pinged?",
     value = ping
   )

   embed.add_field(
     name = "Number of players online",
     value = onlineplayers
   )

   if onlineplayers>6:
     print("lorem ipsum")

   else:
    embed.add_field(
      name = "Username of people online",
      value = onlineplayersname
    )

   embed.add_field(
     name = "Minecraft version of server",
     value = version
   )

   embed.add_field(
     name = "Is the server currently online",
     value = online
   )

   embed.add_field(
     name = "Protocol being used by the server",
     value = protocol
   )

   embed.add_field(
     name = "Hostname",
     value = hostname
   )
   embed.set_thumbnail(
     url = "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp8105351.jpg"
   )

   await ctx.send(embed = embed)


client.run(os.getenv('ENCRYPT'))
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Ignoring exception in command mc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 24, in mc
    data = requests.get(url + arg ).json()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)
```

Please tell me what this means. I have tried multiple times, but my guess is that the JSON function can't handle converting such a large number of files. Please help!

Comment: How are you invoking the command?

Comment: What is the response of the request?

Comment: Example - //mc hypixel.net , where // is a command prefix, mc is the command name, and hypixel.net  is a random server chosen by the user

Comment: Currently I'm not getting any response, just the error I mentioned above.

Comment: This works for me locally... I'm not sure what the problem is but I recommend you trying using aiohttp instead of requests because if the server takes a while to respond you will freeze the bot from using a non-async function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the json file, just check it at line 1 column 5, to ensure that the syntax is correct or not.